# Minimal Postfix master.cf

Tags: postfix

I'm currently deploying yet another Postfix MTA and this time I'd like to thin down the `master.cf` and disable unneeded services to reduce the potential attack surface, and get a better understanding of it in the process.

The MTA should receive emails to virtual users, deliver them to the appropriate maildir and finally relay mail from authenticated users.

Switching to OpenSMTPd (with which my entire configuration can be expressed in a single 15-line file) isn't possible as of right now (no milter support) so I'm stuck with Postfix.

The horror in question :

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

There isn't any man page that describes a minimal configuration, and the man pages of each service don't really tell whether a module is required or not (for some it's easy enough to figure it out, for others it's next to impossible without endless trial and error).

My current failed attempt is the following (submission port omitted, for now I'm only trying to get the mail delivery working) :

```
smtp inet n - - - - smtpd
cleanup unix n - - - 0 cleanup
qmgr unix - - - 300 1 qmgr
rewrite unix - - - - - trivial-rewrite
proxymap unix - - - - - proxymap
virtual unix - n - - - virtual
anvil unix - - - - 1 anvil
local unix - n - - - local
```

This kinda works, except all received mail is only delivered (to maildir) on restarting Postfix, and I'm pretty sure it's incomplete and can't handle bounces, so I'm still looking for an answer.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with your Postfix MTA. For a machine that can only send mail, try this: [http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client)

Comment: I've already read that and there's nothing about master.cf which is what I'm looking for.. I've edited the question with my requirements, which are very basic, receive mail for virtual users and relay mail from authenticated users.

Comment: Your setup above isn't working because apparently you set `qmgr` to private service but postfix default `master.cf` set it to public service. See [man 5 master](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*I wouln't recommend you to remove service from the **default** [master.cf](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/conf/master.cf). You have been bitten by it when you tried minimalist config.*

One reason why postfix has many service is **security**. One of advantage is postfix  run by separate daemon/service to do specific task. So, postfix `master` can adjust permission and privilege per postfix service. For example [qmgr(8) daemon](http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html) does not talk to the outside world, and it can be run at fixed  low  privilege in a chrooted environment.

Anyway I don't have time to do endless trial and error in order to know what's postfix service that can be disabled. So I give you some info about some service and grouping it by several groups.

```
# INPUT SERVICE
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup

# PROCESSING SERVICE
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite

# OUTPUT SERVICE
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp

# HELPER
# Generate bounce
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce

# For postfix recipient/sender verification See www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify

# Outgoing Connection manager 
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

# TLS Cache Manager
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr

# maintains statistics about client connection counts or client request rates
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil

# Needed by mailq command
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq

# Needed by postqueue -f
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush

# Proxymap
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
```